# Jupyter Notebook plots not starting at 0 on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

When I am plotting in Jupyter Notebook, my plots don't extend all the way to the y-axis for some reason. How do I style them so that they look like the first image instead of the second?

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.lmplot(x='Month', y='twp', data=byMonth)
plt.ylim([6000, 15000])
plt.xlim([0, 12])
```

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Comment: Try adding yticks and labels starting from zero.

Answer (score 1):

`sns.lmplot` has a parameter `truncate` which can be set to `False` to draw the plot up till the plot limits. But as `lmplot` is a figure level function, it creates its own figure and axes, so you can't easily set the limits beforehand.

Replacing `sns.lmplot` with the underlying axes-level function `sns.regplot` lets the limits being set before calling the function. Note that `regplot` only creates one subplot, while `lmplot` can create a complete grid of subplots via its `row=`, `col=` and/or `hue=` parameters.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

byMonth = pd.DataFrame({'Month': range(1, 13), 'twp': 13000 - np.random.randint(-800, 2000, 12).cumsum()})

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
plt.xlim([0, 12])
plt.ylim([6000, 15000])
sns.regplot(x='Month', y='twp', data=byMonth, truncate=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

If `lmplot` is really needed, you could temporarily set the x margins wider:

```py
old_xmargin = mpl.rcParams['axes.xmargin']
mpl.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0.2  # temporarily set default x-margin large enough
sns.lmplot(x='Month', y='twp', data=byMonth, truncate=False)
mpl.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = old_xmargin
plt.xlim([0, 12])
plt.ylim([6000, 15000])
```